# Very similar queries, vastly different performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, execution-plan, query-performance

I have two very similar queries

First query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Audits a
    JOIN AuditRelatedIds ari ON a.Id = ari.AuditId
WHERE 
    ari.RelatedId = '1DD87CF1-286B-409A-8C60-3FFEC394FDB1'
    and a.TargetTypeId IN 
    (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
    11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
    21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
    31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,
    41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,
    51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,
    61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,
    71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79)
```

Result: 267479

Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJWTtILyS

---

Second query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Audits a
    JOIN AuditRelatedIds ari ON a.Id = ari.AuditId
WHERE 
    ari.RelatedId = '1DD87CF1-286B-409A-8C60-3FFEC394FDB1'
    and a.TargetTypeId IN 
    (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
    11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
    21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,
    31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,
    41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,
    51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,
    61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,
    71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79)
```

Result: 25650

Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1v79U8kS

---

The first query takes about one second to complete, while the second query takes about 20 seconds. This is completely counter-intuitive to me because the first query has a much higher count than the second. This is on SQL server 2012

Why is there so much of a difference? How can i speedup the second query to be as fast as the first one?

---

Here is the Create table script for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditRelatedIds](
    [AuditId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [RelatedId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AuditTargetTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AuditRelatedIds] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AuditId] ASC,
    [RelatedId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AuditRelatedIdsRelatedId_INCLUDES] ON [dbo].[AuditRelatedIds]
(
    [RelatedId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [AuditId]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditRelatedIds]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AuditRelatedIds_AuditId_Audits_Id] FOREIGN KEY([AuditId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Audits] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditRelatedIds] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AuditRelatedIds_AuditId_Audits_Id]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditRelatedIds]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AuditRelatedIds_AuditTargetTypeId_AuditTargetTypes_Id] FOREIGN KEY([AuditTargetTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AuditTargetTypes] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditRelatedIds] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AuditRelatedIds_AuditTargetTypeId_AuditTargetTypes_Id]
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audits](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TargetTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [TargetId] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [TargetName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Action] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ActionOverride] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserDisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [DescriptionData] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsNotification] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Audits] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AuditsTargetId] ON [dbo].[Audits]
(
    [TargetId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AuditsTargetTypeIdAction_INCLUDES] ON [dbo].[Audits]
(
    [TargetTypeId] ASC,
    [Action] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [TargetId],
    [UserDisplayName]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Audits]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Audits_TargetTypeId_AuditTargetTypes_Id] FOREIGN KEY([TargetTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AuditTargetTypes] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Audits] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Audits_TargetTypeId_AuditTargetTypes_Id]
```

Comment: Would we be able to get some table schema and index details.  As I am sure you noticed plans are a little different but evidently it is making a big difference.  If we can get those details than maybe we can see what options we have.

Comment: As a very quick tip, instead of using IN create a TempTable with a single TINYINT /INT column (clustered) with the numbers you want, and then INNER JOIN to it. Other than that we'll likely need DDL information as @KirkSaunders mentioned above

Comment: Is there anything special about `TargetTypeId = 30`? Seems the plans are different because this one value really skews the amount of data (expected to be) 
returned.

Comment: I realize it's awfully pedantic but the statement *"the first query returns a lot more rows than the second."* is not correct. Both return 1 row ;)

Comment: nothing special about `targetTypeId=30` other than the number of audits with that id

Comment: I suggest you add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables (including all indexes)

Comment: I updated the question with the create table statements for both tables

Comment: You could try changing that index to `(RelatedId, AuditId)`, without the `INCLUDE`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Tl;dr at the bottom*

### Why was the bad plan chosen

The main reason for choosing one plan over the other is the `Estimated total subtree` cost.

This cost was lower for the bad plan than for the better performing plan.

The total estimated subtree cost for the bad plan:

[image]

The total estimated subtree cost for your better performing plan

[image]

---

**The operator estimated costs**

Certain operators can take most of this cost, and could be a reason for the optimizer to choose a different path / plan.

In our better performing plan, the bulk of the `Subtreecost` is calculated on the `index seek` & `nested loops operator` performing the join:

[image]

While for our bad query plan, the `Clustered index seek` operator cost is lower

[image]

Which should explain why the other plan could have been chosen.

(And by adding the parameter `30` increasing the bad plan's cost where it has risen above the `871.510000` estimated cost).  *Estimated guess™*

The better performing plan

[image]

The bad plan

[image]

---

**Where does this take us?**

This information brings us to a way to force the bad query plan on our example 
*(See DML to almost replicate OP's Issue for the data used to replicate the issue)*

By adding an `INNER LOOP JOIN` join hint

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Audits a
   INNER LOOP JOIN AuditRelatedIds ari ON a.Id = ari.AuditId
WHERE 
    ari.RelatedId = '1DD87CF1-286B-409A-8C60-3FFEC394FDB1'
    and a.TargetTypeId IN 
    (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
    11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
    21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,
    31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,
    41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,
    51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,
    61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,
    71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79)
```

It is closer, but has some join order differences:

[image]

---

**Rewriting**

My first rewrite attempt could be storing all these numbers in a temp table instead:

```
CREATE TABLE #Numbers(Numbering INT)
INSERT INTO #Numbers(Numbering)
VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),
(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),
(36),(37),(38),(39),(41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49),(51),(52),
(53),(54),(55),(56),(57),(58),(59),(61),(62),(63),(64),(65),(66),(67),(68),
(69),(71),(72),(73),(74),(75),(76),(77),(78),(79);
```

And then adding a `JOIN` instead of the big `IN()`

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Audits a
   INNER LOOP JOIN AuditRelatedIds ari ON a.Id = ari.AuditId
   INNER JOIN #Numbers
   ON Numbering = a.TargetTypeId
WHERE 
    ari.RelatedId = '1DD87CF1-286B-409A-8C60-3FFEC394FDB1';
```

Our query plan is different but not yet fixed:

[image]

with a huge estimated operator cost on the `AuditRelatedIds` table

[image]

---

*Here is where I noticed that*

**The reason that I cannot  directly recreate your plan is optimized bitmap filtering.**

I can recreate your plan by disabling optimized bitmap filters by using traceflags `7497` & `7498`

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Audits a 
   INNER JOIN AuditRelatedIds  ari ON a.Id = ari.AuditId 
   INNER JOIN #Numbers
   ON Numbering = a.TargetTypeId
WHERE 
    ari.RelatedId = '1DD87CF1-286B-409A-8C60-3FFEC394FDB1'
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 7497, QUERYTRACEON 7498);
```

More information on optimized bitmap filters [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/11/sql-plan/hash-joins-on-nullable-columns).

[image]

This means, that without the bitmap filters, the optimizer deems it better to first join to the `#number` table and then join to the `AuditRelatedIds` table.

When forcing the order  `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 7497, QUERYTRACEON 7498, FORCE ORDER);` we can see why:

[image]

&
[image]

*Not good*

---

**Removing the ability to go parallel with maxdop 1**

When adding `MAXDOP 1` the query performs faster, single threaded.

*And adding this index*

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AuditRelatedIdsRelatedId_AuditId] ON [dbo].[AuditRelatedIds]
(
    [RelatedId] ASC,
    [AuditId] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY];
```

[image]

While using a merge join.
[image]

The same is true when we remove the force order query hint or not using the #Numbers table and using the `IN()` instead.

My advice would be to look into adding `MAXDOP(1)` and see if that helps your query, with a rewrite if needed.

Ofcourse you should also keep in mind that on my end it performs even better due to the optimized bitmap filtering & actually using multiple threads to good effect:

[image]

[image]

---

**TL;DR**

Estimated costs will define the plan chosen, I was able to replicate the behaviour and saw that `optimized bitmap filters` + `parallellism` operators where added on my end to perform the query in a performant and fast manner.

You could look into adding `MAXDOP(1)` to your query as a way to hopefully get the same controlled outcome each time, with a `merge join` and no 'bad' `parallellism`.

Upgrading to a newer version and using a higher cardinality estimator version than  `CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70"` might also help.

A numbers temporary table to do the multi value filtering can also help.

---

### DML to almost replicate OP's Issue

*I spent more time on this than i would like to admit*

```
set NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @I INT = 0
WHILE @I < 56
BEGIN
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Audits] WITH(TABLOCK) 
([TargetTypeId],
    [TargetId],
    [TargetName],
    [Action],
    [ActionOverride] ,
    [Date] ,
    [UserDisplayName],
    [DescriptionData],
    [IsNotification]) 
SELECT top(500000) CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) / 10000 = 30 then 29 ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) / 10000 END as rownum2 -- TILL 50 and no 30
,'bla','bla2',1,1,getdate(),'bla3','Bla4',1
FROM master.dbo.spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master.dbo.spt_values spt2;
SET @I +=1;
END

-- 'Bad Query matches'
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[AuditRelatedIds] WITH(TABLOCK)
    ([AuditId] ,
    [RelatedId]  ,
    [AuditTargetTypeId])
SELECT
TOP(25650)
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rownum1, 
('1DD87CF1-286B-409A-8C60-3FFEC394FDB1') , 
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) / 510 = 30 then 29 ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) / 510 END as rownum2 -- TILL 50 and no 30
FROM master.dbo.spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master.dbo.spt_values spt2

-- Extra matches with 30
SELECT MAX([Id]) FROM [dbo].[Audits];
--28000001 Upper value

INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Audits] WITH(TABLOCK) 
([TargetTypeId],
    [TargetId],
    [TargetName],
    [Action],
    [ActionOverride] ,
    [Date] ,
    [UserDisplayName],
    [DescriptionData],
    [IsNotification]) 
SELECT top(241829) 30 as rownum2 -- TILL 50 and no 30
,'bla','bla2',1,1,getdate(),'bla3','Bla4',1
FROM master.dbo.spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master.dbo.spt_values spt2;



;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rownum1, 
('1DD87CF1-286B-409A-8C60-3FFEC394FDB1') as gu , 
30 as rownum2 -- TILL 50 and no 30
FROM master.dbo.spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master.dbo.spt_values spt2
CROSS APPLY master.dbo.spt_values spt3
)
--267479 - 25650 = 241829
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[AuditRelatedIds] WITH(TABLOCK)
    ([AuditId] ,
    [RelatedId]  ,
    [AuditTargetTypeId])

SELECT TOP(241829) rownum1,gu,rownum2 FROM CTE
WHERE rownum1 > 28000001
ORDER BY rownum1 ASC;
```

Comment: Very nice explanation! Adding `MAXDOP 0` seems to have fixed it. Thank you very much!

Comment: MAXDOP 1 ** (typo)

Comment: @Chocoman Great! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the primary difference between the two plans is the difference in what is the "Primary Filter".

With the first version the main filter was deriving which `Audit.ID` is related to `ari.RelatedId = '1DD87CF1-286B-409A-8C60-3FFEC394FDB1'` then filter that list down to those who's `Audit.TargetTypeID` were in the list.

With the second version the main filter was deriving which `Audit.ID` is related to the list of `Audit.TargetTypeID`.

Since the addition of `Audit.TargetTypeID = 30` appeared to dramatically increase the record count (267,479 and 25,650 respectively according to the Original Question).  That is probably why the execution plans are different.  (As I understand it) SQL will try to do the most selective function first and then apply the rest of the rules after that.  With the first version, querying by `AuditRelatedID.RelatedID` to then find `Audit.ID` was probably more selective than trying to use `Audit.TargetTypeID` to then find `Audit.ID`.

To ypercube's credit.  You can certainly update `[AuditRelatedIds].[IX_AuditRelatedIdsRelatedId_INCLUDES]` to have both `RelatedID` and `AuditID` as part of in index instead of having `AuditID` as part of an `INCLUDE`.  It shouldn't take up any additional index space and would allow you to use both columns in `JOIN` clauses.  That may help the Query Optimizer create the same execution plan for both queries.

Operating with a similar logic, there may be some benefit to an index on `Audit` which contains `TargetTypeID ASC, ID ASC` on the actual ordered/filtering nodes (not as part of the `INCLUDE`).  This should allow the Query optimizer to filter by `Audit.TargetTypeID` then quickly join to `AuditReferenceIds.AuditID`.  Now this may end up with both queries choosing the less efficient plan so I would only give it a shot after trying ypercube's recommendation.